# React.useContext appearing as undefined

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks, react-context, use-context, createcontext

This is my first time using the React context hooks in an app and my context default value keeps appearing as "undefined."

Troubleshooting so far:

- I've made sure React.createContext is in a separate file (context.js)
- I've made sure the child component is wrapped within the Provider
- I'm providing a default value to React.createContext()

All of my code can be found in this CodeSandbox link below:

https://codesandbox.io/s/react-context-troubleshooting-ojnb2?file=/src/child.js

Comment: please make following change in child file const  selectedBackground  = useContext(SelectedBackgroundContext);

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In your [App.js](https://codesandbox.io/s/react-context-troubleshooting-ojnb2?file=/src/App.js) file, you're passing `value` a string:

```js
import React, { useContext } from "react";
import { SelectedBackgroundContext } from "./context";
import Child from "./child";

function App() {
  const { selectedBackground } = useContext(SelectedBackgroundContext);

  // selectedBackground is just a string, so value = "https://...", which is invalid, the value, in your case, should be an object
  return (
    <SelectedBackgroundContext.Provider value={selectedBackground}>
      <Child />
    </SelectedBackgroundContext.Provider>
  );
}

export default App;
```

Instead, `value` needs to be an object, with a `selectedBackground` property that contains the string:

```js
import React, { useContext } from "react";
import { SelectedBackgroundContext } from "./context";
import Child from "./child";

function App() {
  const { selectedBackground, selectBackground } = useContext(
    SelectedBackgroundContext
  );
  // alternatively, just collect all context, without destructuring,
  // and pass it to the "value" prop: value={context}
  // const context = useContext(SelectedBackgroundContext);


  // you're also missing the "selectBackground" function, which should be added to this "value" prop
  return (
    <SelectedBackgroundContext.Provider
      value={{ selectedBackground, selectBackground }}
    >
      <Child />
    </SelectedBackgroundContext.Provider>
  );
}

export default App;
```

Since you've created context using an object:

```json
{
  selectedBackground:
    "https://lp-cms-production.imgix.net/2019-06/81377873%20.jpg?fit=crop&q=40&sharp=10&vib=20&auto=format&ixlib=react-8.6.4",
  selectBackground: () => {}
}
```

The `value` property of the provider should also be an object!

```
value={{ selectedBackground, selectBackground }}
```

Working demo:

[image: Edit React Context Troubleshooting (forked)]

Answer (score 0):

I have changed your code to following and its working.

```
import React, { useContext } from "react";
import { SelectedBackgroundContext } from "./context";

export default function Child() {
  const  selectedBackground  = useContext(SelectedBackgroundContext);
  // you can comment out line5 above and uncomment line7 below to verify all other code works
  //let selectedBackground = 'https://lp-cms-production.imgix.net/2019-06/81377873%20.jpg?fit=crop&q=40&sharp=10&vib=20&auto=format&ixlib=react-8.6.4'

  const renderSelected = (context) => {
    console.log("Background img src is: " + context); //appears as undefined

    if (context) {
      return (
        <img
          style={{ height: "200px" }}
          src={context}
          key={context + "Thumbnail"}
          alt={"thumbnail of " + context}
        />
      );
    } else {
      return <p>None</p>;
    }
  };

  return (
    <div>
      <p>Background:}</p> {renderSelected(selectedBackground)}
    </div>
  );
}
```

because your are not passing object from context value that is why no need of

```
const  {selectedBackground}  = useContext(SelectedBackgroundContext);
```

more about deconstructing variable
https://www.javascripttutorial.net/es6/javascript-object-destructuring/